# Import hierarchichal JSON file into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have looked for solutions to my problem but couldn't find anything that applies. I'm trying to import a high dimension JSON file into a Pandas dataframe.

The structure is something like:

```
{   'manufacturing_plant_events':
        {   'data':
            {   'shiftInformation':
                {   'shift1':
                    { 'color': 'red'
                        , 'amount' : 32
                        , 'order' : None
                    },
                    'shift2':
                    { 'color': 'blue'
                        , 'amount' : 44
                        , 'order' : 1
                    },
                    'shift3':
                    { 'color': 'green'
                        , 'amount' : 98
                        , 'order' : 2
                    }
                }
            ...}
        ...}
    }
```

I have tried numerous solutions including:

- json.loads()
- pd.DataFrame(json)
- json_normalize(json)
- pd.read_json(json)

and others, I've tried flattening my array and converting it into a dataframe bu that didn't work either. I'm not sure if this is even possible or if the dataframe supports only a few levels of nested.

The flattening I've tried was to just try and create columns in a dataframe that contain the leaf information. Hence, I'm also fine with a dataframe which has the following column names the full path and the value, the actual value stored in the node.

First row in my dataframe:

```
(
manufacturing_plant_events.data.shiftInformation.shift1.color
'red'

manufacturing_plant_events.data.shiftInformation.shift1.amount
32

manufacturing_plant_events.data.shiftInformation.shift1.order
None
)
```

and so on.

Any suggestion on how to solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: A possible solution: once you flatten your json to a pandas dataframe, you can split the label by `.` into new columns.

Comment: you want each row to be `shiftX`? So row 1 is `shift1`, row 2 `shift2`, etc?

Comment: can you share the whole json file? or atleast as much as to what you would want as 2 rows of your data?

Comment: Pandas dataframe are not good at processing hierachical data. They have a notion of row and column like CSV files or Excel spreadsheet, so you should decide what you want your dataframe to look like, load the json with `json.load`, convert that to 2D data in a format suitable for `pd.DataFrame` and build the dataframe from that.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a dataframe by flattening the dict :

```py
import pandas as pd

def flat_dict(dictionary, prefix):
    if type(dictionary) == dict:
        rows = []

        for key, items in dictionary.items():
            rows += flat_dict(items, prefix + [key])   

        return rows

    else:
        return [prefix + [dictionary]]

def dict_to_df(dictionary):        
    return pd.DataFrame(flat_dict(dictionary, []))
```

Sure you need to import your json as a dict first thanks to `json` package.